# How do you fill a Java HashMap with multiple instances of related subclasses?

Tags: java

I have a superclass called "Canvas," from which I create several subclasses. I want to store instances of those subclasses in a dictionary. So I tried setting up my code as follows:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas();



        Menu menu = new Menu();
        Instructions instructions = new Instructions();
        Map<String, Canvas> screens = new HashMap<String, Canvas>();
        screens.put("menu", menu);
        screens.put("instructions", instructions);
```

So, being that the things I want to add to the dictionary are all subclasses of my Canvas class, I set up the hashtable to accept that Type. And this works.. for the most part. However, the big problem is that I cannot access any of the subclass' methods. I can only call methods that exist in the superclass.

If I attempt to do something like,

```
screens.get("menu").some_func_in_subclass();
```

The compiler spits out a "Can not find symbol" message.

So, if I have something like this:

```
SuperClass
  |
  |
  +------------------------------------   
        |               |             |
     SubClass1     SubClass2     SubClass3
```

How would I store instances of those subclasses in a HashMap?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's the idea of polymorphism - all the sub-classes of `Canvas` share the same methods (from the `Canvas` super class) but if you add methods to those classes they are not shared any longer.

One way would be to cast your result (assuming you have checked that the value really is a `Menu`):

```
((Menu)screens.get("menu")).some_func_in_subclass();
```

But it defeats the purpose of holding everything in a `Map<String, Canvas>` in the first place.

In the end, either you need `Canvas` objects, and you should not have to call sub-classes methods, or you need something more specific and there probably is a design issue.

Answer (score 1):

How are you figuring out the type of the SubClass?

If you add instances of `SubClass1`, and `SubClass2`, how would *you* determine which special method to call?

You can, for instance, check the type of the content:

```
Map<String, Canvas> map = new HashMap<String,Canvas>();
map.put("a", new SubClass1());
map.put("b", new SubClass2());

if(map.get("a") instanceof SubClass1){
  // safe to cast, we checked!
  SubClass1 inst = (SubClass1) map.get("a");
  inst.some_func_in_subclass();
}
```

Basically, adding things as `Canvas` makes only the `Canvas` methods available. You *can* cast *upwards* to a more specific type, but you should do so with care, checking the type is what you expect, as shown above.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using strings as your type, consider using `Class` variables:

```
public class Main {
    static Map<Class, Canvas> screens = new HashMap<Class<?>, Canvas>();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Menu menu = new Menu();
        Instructions instructions = new Instructions();
        screens.put(menu.getClass(), menu);
        screens.put(instructions.getClass(), instructions);
    }

    public static T getScreen<T>() {
        return (T)screens.get(T);
    }
}
```

Then, later, you can do:

```
getScreen<Menu.class>().some_func_in_subclass();
```

and the compiler will know what you mean.